# Lambda filename trigger to copy specific file on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an s3 bucket where `.mxf` files are deposited, these files have names like:

```
local01_area_174244_Title for media.mxf
local02_zone_164425_Media_information.mxf
```

In another bucket I have files that are the metadata referring to these files, however, the name is not necessarily the same.

It was necessary, as soon as the `.mxf` files were placed in the bucket, that part of the name was extracted to search the metadata files in another bucket

The metadata files related to the `.mxf` above will be `.xml` and the names would be like:

```
file01_area_174244_Metadata media01.xml
02local_zone_164425_Media_metadata.xml
```

Generally, what is repeated is the ID of the content, in the case of files, only the fields:

```
174244
164425
```

Always after the second underscore `(_ _)` and the third `(_)`

Could anyone help me with the best way to resolve this issue?

I've tried a few things in Lambda, but I don't know anything about that feature.

Comment: Generally you'll write a Lambda that is triggered by which ever file is dropped last.  If that the `.mxf` file then it will be triggered by that.  The Lambda would get information about the `.mxf` file and then read the other bucket to see if the meta data exists.  What programming environment do you use?  Where are you stuck?  The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) should help you get started.

Comment: What is your final objective? Your question title mentions copying a specific file, but the details in your question don't actually say what you'd like to do. Also, do you know in what order the files will be created? The reason I ask is that you would presumably want something to trigger your code -- or will you be running your code manually? Please Edit your question and provide more information about the general flow of what you would like to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, I created the trigger to monitor s3 when the .mxf file drops into the bucket folder, what I couldn't do is filter the part specific to the name of the .mxf files and look for the corresponding metadata file in the other bucket.

I'm only using aws (lambda) Python 3.9 services and I'm stuck on that second part, which is filtering the file name part and
fetch the corresponding information from the other bucket.

As for the final objective, it would be the copy of specific files related to the files that will be deposited in a bucket.

The .mxf files are created in random order, as requested in an application, while the .xml metadata files will already be in their bucket, but these files will not always exist, therefore, the check would have to be done and if the .xml exists, copy it to the output bucket.

The code would be triggered automatically by the s3 trigger in Lambda.